# how to iterate over UTF-8 in Python?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

How do I iterate over utf 8?

```
import string

for character in string.printable[1:]:
    print (character)
```

Presumably there's a similar approach for UTF-8?

Comment: Please clarify that you want to iterate over the bytes of the multi-byte UTF-8 encoding?  Also note there are no multi-byte characters in `string.printable`.

Comment: What I was thinking was to start with a UTF 8 character, and then increment the char

Comment: `UTF-8` is not a character, it is an specific encoding method to convert Unicode characters to bytes.  Suggested reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: Or this: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Presumably there's a similar approach for UTF-8?

Do you want to know which codepoints are printable outside of the ascii range? Or do you want the utf8 encodings of printable characters?

## To get all printable codepoints for all of unicode:

```
unicode_max = 0x10ffff
printable_glyphs = [ chr(x) for x in range(0, unicode_max+1) if chr(x).isprintable() ]
```

As mentioned above, utf8 is an encoding. That's when text is mapped to specific bytes, so that other programs can share data.

Text in-memory is not utf8. Every character/glyph has a single codepoint.

## Converting to utf-8

```
import unicodedata
monkey = unicodedata.lookup('monkey')

print(f"""
    glyph: {monkey}
    codepoint: Dec: {ord(monkey)}
    codepoint: Hex:  {hex(ord(monkey))}

    utf8: { monkey.encode('utf8', errors='strict') }
    utf16: { monkey.encode('utf16', errors='strict') }
    utf32: { monkey.encode('utf32', errors='strict') }
""")
```

outputs:

```
glyph: 
codepoint: Dec: 128018
codepoint: Hex:  0x1f412

 utf8: b'\xf0\x9f\x90\x92'
utf16: b'\xff\xfe=\xd8\x12\xdc'
utf32: b'\xff\xfe\x00\x00\x12\xf4\x01\x00'
```